# Shortcode inside shortcode of CF7DB-extention (Wordpress Contact form 7 to database plugin)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, shortcode

Is there a way to use a shortcode inside the CF7DB shortcodes ([Wordpress plugin](https://github.com/mdsimpson/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/))?

Something like this:
`[cfdb-table form=”Registration 3GC” search=”[user_email]”]` where `[user_email]` is the e-mail address of the logged in user. The `[user_email]` shortcode is being created by an other plugin.

I want logged in users show their filled in contact 7 form in the front-end part of the site. Maybe there is an other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$email = do_shortcode("[user_email]");
echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="Registration 3GC" search="'. $email .'"]');
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! I changed it a little bit: deleted the `$email = do_shortcode("[user_email]");` part and used Wordpress get_current_user function instead! But thanks anyways